# Why my POST request work only with debugger?

Tags: node.js, postman, crud

I try to write CRUD and checking it up with Postman.

When I use a debugger at the end of the post request it's working.

Problem: When I remove the debugger and try to run the code nothing happens - only error: "Could not get any response". How can I make my post to work well without debugger?

***For example, I send this as JSON through postman like this:

```
{   
    "id":3,
    "name": "Ron",
    "phone": "01323133333"
}
```

this is the relevant code:

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
db = require('./db');
app.use(express.static('public'));
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = 1400;
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})

//post request:
app.post('/user' , (req,res)=> {
    const {body} = req,
    {id,name,phone} = body

    db.query(`INSERT INTO public.users(
        id, name, phone)
        VALUES (${id}, '${name}', '${phone}');`,(err,dbRes)=>{
            if(err)
            res.status(400).send(err);

            else
            {
                res.send(dbRes.rows);
            }
        })
})
```

db.js:

```
const {Client} = require ('pg');

const client = new Client ({
    user:'postgres',
    host:'localhost',
    database:'nodeapp',
    password:'123456',
    port:5432
  })

  client.connect();

module.exports = client;
```

Thank you !

Comment: What is HTTP error code when you _"Could not get any response"_ message?

Comment: You need to add error handling for [pg.Client](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#client.connect) to determine if it is connected or not.